# Angular is redirecting to home page even when login credentials are false

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, validation, authentication

I'm sorry to ask this, but I've been working on it for hours now and still can't figure it out. We are using an API to pull data from a database for a members-only site. The login form should redirect to the home page of the site if information is correct, else it should show a popup that says: "invalid username and password" (we would also like an error message if fields are left blank). However the login will still go to the home page whether the information is correct or not.

Here is the html form - login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src ="angular.js"></script>
    <script src ="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CMPS1/css/login.css">
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app = "sga">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">

        <div class="body"></div>
        <div class="grad"></div>
        <div class="header">
            <div><a style="color:gold">SGA</a><span><a style="color: seagreen"><strong>Connect</strong></a></span></div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="login">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" ng-model="username" required><br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="password" required><br>
            <input type="button" value="Login"  ng-click="login(username,password)">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

our controller/api -- login_controller.php (based off code igniter framework)

```
<?php
class Login_controller extends CI_Controller
{

    function validate(){
//       when posting  json data to the api
        $json = key($this->input->post(NULL, TRUE));
        $json = json_decode($json);
        $username = $json->username;
        $password = md5($json->password);
//        when posting with a normal post method with parameters
//        $username = $this->input->post('username');
//        $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
        $this->load->model('Membership_model');
        $query = $this-Membership_model->validate($username,$password);
        if($query) {
            $data['status']= true;
        }
        else{
            $data['status'] = false;

        }

        $this->load->view('verify.php', $data);
    }

}
?>
```

the angular file -- app.js

```
(function() {
    angular.module("sga",[])
        .controller("MainController",["$scope","$http",function($scope,$http){
        $scope.login = function (username, password) {

            var req = {
                url: 'http://localhost/CMPS1/API/application/controllers/Login_controller/validate',
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    username: username,
                    password: password
                },
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

            };

            if ($http(req).then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data) {
                        window.open('index.html', '_self');
                    }
                }));

            else {
                alert("Invalid username or password.");
            }
        };

    }]);

})();
```

the file which actually checks the database to see if info is correct -- membership_model.php

```
<?php
class Membership_model extends CI_Model{
    function validate($username,$password){
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$password);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        if($query->num_rows() == 1){
            return $query;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You're not handling the response correctly. Should be `if (response.data) { //navigate to home page } else  { //alert invalid }`, and I would be skeptical about why your `$http` is inside an `if`? And lastly, make sure `response` is actually returning what you think it should be.

Comment: What you have write verify.php?

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs is used to create single page applications. In your MainController you are redirecting the user to index.html on success.

You should have two views, one for login and another for home page in angularjs.
Include  in your index.html and create routes for login and home page.

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'login'
  })
  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'home'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

});

In the success callback just redirect to /home using "$location.path( "/home" );"